# jQuery load() method conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 html pages in root folder, index.html and try.html(which will be loaded to index's div (#content)). On first step, when I click on Button 01 of index.html, it loads try.html in index.html's div successfully. But, when i further click on try.html's button(which is now loaded in index.html's div), It doesn't perform function properly and executes it before event occurance. now i want to access the button of try.html on proper event, what can i do for this?

As i have tried, it executes before actual event . (code below)

http://pastebin.com/RGcXGFXY
Relevant code:

```
$('document').ready(function(){

    $('#myBtn').click(function(){
        $('#content').load('try.html');
        $('#myBtn2').click(alert('It Works'));
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should write click handler for `#myBtn2` properly

```
$('#myBtn2').click(function() { 
  alert('It Works');
});
```

or actually it can be even outside first `#myBtn` click handler,

```
$('#myBtn').click(function(){
   $('#content').load('try.html');
});

$(document).on('click', '#myBtn2', function(){
   alert('It Works')
});
```

for more refer to [jQuery.on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: now you can also mark this answer as correct, Jigar

Comment: @JigarPatel: Changing the question title to `[solved]` is not how you mark a question as solved: the SO way is to makr the helpful answer as _accepted_. Read the help section for details. Also note that I've edited your question to contain the actual code that was causing the problem. In the help section, it's explained that links alone do not suffice: links don't keep on working. The people here should be able to see both the code itself, and the answers that solved the issue, without relying on other sites actually hosting the code that is being discussed. (PS: Welcome to the site)

Comment: worked perfect . . . does it mean I will have to same code for other events too?

Comment: Sorry @EliasVanOotegem ... I am new on Stackoverflow. I will understand and follow satckoverflow's standards strictly with my best

Comment: @JigarPatel: NP, just thought I point out the help section, it tells you what is expected, and what makes a good question. Like I said: welcome to the site. There are some guidelines that new users should be aware of, but that's why _"seasoned"_ users are expected to check out first questions (moderator tools, see privileges page). Things to keep in mind: comments saying _"thanks"_ are discouraged, not voting is considered ungrateful, and not accepting answers will cause people not to bother answering, and questions shouldn't contain _"hello"_ or _"thanks"_. But most importantly: have fun.

Comment: Some of these rules may seem odd, but you can discuss them on the meta site, but first read the help section: the rationale behind these rules/guidelines is explained. 9/10, it makes sense...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, I'll check help section for sure , and rules are not odd, in fact it provides a standard for communication and helps communicate effectively as well as clearly.

Comment: @JigarPatel: Just wanted to make it clear that I'm not saying you're a _"bad user"_, because you said (a few comments back) that you were sorry. No need to apologize, I wanted to make that clear. I'll leave you to check the help, read it through, and you'll merit your first badge (a badge is a sort of symbolic reward for achievements)

Comment: okay, I'll take care of rules from now onward. @EliasVanOotegem